# Excel Formula for Random selection of contents in two non adjacent cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have successfully used a formula for randomly selecting cell contents in a range of adjacent columns using the following formula:

=INDEX(L3:Q3, RANDBETWEEN(1, 6))

I would now like to randomly select cell contents from one of two columns which are not adjacent. How can I make adapt the below formula to accomplish this?

=INDEX(I3,R3, RANDBETWEEN(1, 2))

Answer (score 2):

Use CHOOSE:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),I1,R1)
```

Comment: That's really a good alternative, I was thinking to reinvent the first range parameter of `Index()` :)

Comment: @user8553155 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.